# replacement using regex expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an HTML string in java which has data within certain attributes

One example being

```
<img class="show-grid" src="http://localhost:4502/content/dam/original" alt="4.7-products.jpg">
```

Now, the problem that I have is I want to append some string at the end of the string which is within src attribute (string starting with http and ending with original here) which is the url.

Only thing I know:

- String would always start with `http`.

Somethings I don't know

- What would be the ending sequence of the string.
- There could be another attribute after the target attribute here(target attribute is src in this case).

I tried with following regex:

```
target.search(/(\bhttp.*\"\b)/gi)
```

The idea is to find to all strings:

- Which start with `http` and end with `"`.

So, I thought this regex will give me the following string:

`http://localhost:4502/content/dam/original"`

But instead it gives me:

`http://localhost:4502/content/dam/original" alt="`

Any idea why it goes beyond the current word, Is it because it looks for space between words and then when it finds `"` in the space seperated new word it stops its search there .

How can I modify `target.search(/(\bhttp.*\"\b)/gi)` to get the desired result there?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want _all_ strings that start with `http` and ends with `"`? only those in img src? or some other criteria?

Comment: all strings that start with http and end when first occurence of " is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Just split and add back in the character you need with a [positive lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
String string = "http://yourtestinthstsdfasdfasdfhttp://moreteststrings";
String[] parts = string.split("(?=http)");
String part1 = parts[0]; // is http://yourtestinthstsdfasdfasdf
String part2 = parts[1]; // is http://moreteststrings
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex are "greedy" (see : <del>https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp</del>  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). To change it, modify `/(\bhttp.*\"\b)/` to `/(\bhttp.*?\"\b)/`.

Edit : This still does not work, see my message below

Comment: Thanks @sidney , tim .  I tried it . I used var abc = htmlResponse.replace(/(\bhttp.*?\"\b)/gi, function myFunc(x){return "hi";});
I expected src="hi alt="4.7-products.jpg"> instead I got src="hi4.7-products.jpg"

Comment: @Geek I just tried it, this one : `/(?:src=")(http:.[^"]*)/gi.exec(s)[1]` will work `[1]` is here for extracting the first matching (capturing) group from the whole match. The main difference with your is `.[^"]` instead of `. `which will match everything except ".

Comment: @TimTow thanks. But what is the problem with regex /(\bhttp.*?\"\b)/. Why is it going wo the second occurence of ".

Comment: @Geek I think (not sure) it's because `.*` eats it, maybe `.[^"]*` would fix it.

Comment: It seems to be your ending \b which cause the problem

Comment: `\bhttp.*?\"\b` - the `\"\b` doesnt work because it selects occurrence where a word boundary is right after a double quote. The reason why the `"` in `original" alt=` is not selected because there's a whitespace in between the `"` and the word boundary which is located at `a`.

Comment: @SWLim Why is the word boundary considered to be `a`? Isn't a word boundary a space character?

Comment: @Geek @sidney I just googled the word boundary, the problem seems to be that \b consider a word as something composed of [a-zA-Z0-9_] and not " so the word boundary is `...al` and not `...al"`

Comment: @SWLim But the end of a word is also a word boundary

Comment: `original<double quote><space><word boundary here>alt=`. I think this would be a clearer picture =). If you try `\"\s\b`, you will then see it being selected. On the contrary, `alt=<double quote><number 4>.7` has no space, hence it being selected.

Comment: @M.Timtow, yeah. Hence why `http.+?\b\"` would work too. (note that `\"` is after `\b`)

Comment: @M.Timtow I think the confusion in the first place was caused by the ordering of `\b` and `\"` haha. Just to add on, you can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript) to test instead of using console :D

Comment: @SWLim Yes, I misunderstood your msg earlier, finally after 3000 msgs :)

Answer (score 0):

That regex is using the default greedy modifiers. This means that it is searching for *as many* `*` (any characters) as it can find. Instead, what you are looking for is the `*?` (zero or more, non-greedy) modifier, which changes this behaviour.

Your new regex search would look like:

```
target.search(/http.*?\"/gi)
```

Comment: somehow did not work for me . I used var abc = htmlResponse.replace(/(\bhttp.*?\"\b)/gi, function myFunc(x){return "hi";}); I expected src="hi alt="4.7-products.jpg"> instead I got src="hi4.7-products.jpg

Comment: @Geek I'm not actually too sure how `\b` works, but I got rid of it: `/http.*?\"/gi` and it worked.

Comment: It worked . Thanks a lot champion.How can I accept this answer.

Comment: `\bhttp.*?(?=\")` if you don't want the match to include the last `"`.

Comment: @sidney see my [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169699/replacement-using-regex-expression-in-javascript#comment63767558_38169762) under M.Timtows for the explanation about `\"\b`

Comment: @Geek [Here's the guide for when someone answers to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Awesome Guys. Thanks 3 of you. I just started with regex today and already learnt a lot. Appreciate prompt answers.

Answer (score 0):

`/http.*(?=\"\s)/gi` would match anything from http until the end quote followed by a white space. It uses (?=) which is called Positive Lookahead.

A different approach, if you just want to match anything inside the **src** attribute without need to speculate if http string exists: `src="([^"]*)`.

You can play with it https://regex101.com/r/rH0yZ2/3.

Comment: thanks. But unfortunately, the strings starting with http can be under any attribute. So, I am doing a full text scan for strings starting with http.